# Python: How to get access to values in specific nested lists

Tags: python

If I have the nested list:

```
[
 ['14', '6'],
 ['11', '9'],
 ['3', '-12'],
 ['14', '-6'],
 ['11', '8'],
 ['7', '1'],
 ['4', '-6'],
 ['3', '-12'],
 ['1', '2']
]
```

How would I be able to search through each list, and compare the `i[[1]]` values to every other item in the list? I'm trying to make it so that if the `i[0]` value is equal to another `i[0]` value in the list, I want to add their `i[[1]]` values together. For example. `['11', '9']` and `['11','8']` have the same `i[0]` values, so I would then want them to be added together and make ['11', '17'].

[image]

Comment: Generally when people have a question here, they show what effort they've made so far, in the form of a [mre]. Without one, it's basically just you asking for people to give you code even though you haven't made any apparent effort. The [tour] and [ask] page go into more detail, I suggest reading those.

Answer (score 0):

One easy option is to treat the first number as a key in a dict, and then set/add on the second number:

```
i =  [['14', '6'], ['11', '9'], ['3', '-12'], ['14', '-6'], ['11', '8'], ['7', '1'], ['4', '-6'], ['3', '-12'], ['1', '2']]

y = {}
for x in i:
    if x[0] in y:
        y[x[0]] += int(x[1])
    else:
        y[x[0]] = int(x[1])

print(y)
# Or if you need a list of pairs...
print(list(y.items())
```

> {'14': 0, '11': 17, '3': -24, '7': 1, '4': -6, '1': 2}
> [('14', 0), ('11', 17), ('3', -24), ('7', 1), ('4', -6), ('1', 2)]

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to collect the aggregates:

```
agg = {}
for x, y in lst:
    agg[x] = agg.get(x, 0) + int(y)

[[k, str(v)] for k, v in agg.items()]
# [['14', '0'], ['11', '17'], ['3', '-24'], ['7', '1'], ['4', '-6'], ['1', '2']]
```